How to import in place vhdx WSL2 from a NAS with User credentials
I currently have a .vhdx file on my NAS of a distribution and I would like to be able to import and run the distribute from the NAS. Where I am currently at:
In PowerShell (administrator mode)
I have ran this command successfully:
wsl --import-in-place my_distro_name "\\path_to_my_NAS_share_directory\ext4.vhdx"
and it imports just fine.
then when I run
wsl -d my_distro_name
I get the following error:

Failed to attach disk '\path_to_my_NAS_share_directory\ext4.vhdx' to WSL2: The
user name or password is incorrect.
Error code: Wsl/Service/CreateInstance/MountVhd/HCS/0x8007052e

I don't know where to look for setting the credentials for WSL to be able to access the NAS directory location.
Any direction or help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you very much in advance.
